# How to upload a Excel file along with a new GUID append with File name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload an excel file,  and I want to append Guid with the file name.

I'm using C# MVC for this

```
public ActionResult ValidateUploadedFile()
        {
            DataExchangeDefinitionViewModel dataExchangeDefinitionVM = new DataExchangeDefinitionViewModel();
            DataExchangeDefinition dataExchangeDefinitionObj = new DataExchangeDefinition();

            //  Get all files from Request object  
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
            HttpPostedFileBase file = files[0];

            try
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fname;
                    // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                    if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Guid guidObj = Guid.NewGuid();
                        fname = file.FileName + guidObj.ToString();
                    }                    
                    fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Uploads/ImportExcel"), fname);
                    if (_dataExchangeBusiness.IsExcelFile(fname)==true)
                    {                       
                        file.SaveAs(fname);
                        return Json(new { Result = "true", Message = "" });

                    }
                     else
                    {
                        return Json(new { Result = "false", Message = "" });
                    }                                      
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            // return Json(new { Result = "OK" ,Message="File validated succesfully"});
            return null;
        }
```

Actually, the file is uploaded properly. I want to append Guid with the file name. When I append with Guid with file name it appends after the file extension.

like this **OtherExpense_01.01.2011_E20.xlsx7ac9dbdb-67bb-434c-8465-6a1f7e5bfc83**
i'm expecting result like this **OtherExpense_01.01.2011_E20_7ac9dbdb-67bb-434c-8465-6a1f7e5bfc83.xlsx**

Comment: `file.FileName`has the full name of the file, including extension. You'll have to play with the FileName string. Something like `fname = file.FileName.Substring(0, file.FileName.Length-5) + guidObj.ToString() + ".xlsx";` should work, maybe you'll have to play with ` file.FileName.Length-5` until you properly clean the file extension. You can also set a variable for the extension, so you avoid magic strings.

Comment: But how can we specify particular length. File name length may vary

Comment: Is there any function like _GetExtension(fname)_ to get file name with out extension

Comment: @dhanildinesan `file.FileName.Length` gives you the length of the file name, including the extension. The -5 is to take out the last 5 chars of the string. [Here you have](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xwjBF1) a little example showing how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) and [`Path.GetExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods to concatenate filename with GUID (note that both of them requires `System.IO` namespace):

```
Guid guidObj = Guid.NewGuid();

string baseName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

fname = baseName + guidObj.ToString() + extension;
```

Comment: Let me try this one

Comment: This one Works.Thank you